# Button click and ListView click

Tags: android, listview, buttonclick, onitemclick

I have a `ListView`. on click of a list item I start a `Activity`. Now I have added a `Button` on that `ListView` and onclick of a button I want to start a another activity. After adding a Button, I can click on the button and start a Activity but now I can not click a list item. What happened to listview's item click ??

Comment: You want click on both? the item and button?

Comment: Yes, and go to diff activities

Comment: post the code related to clickListeners of the button and the list item.

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
      
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TaskDetails.class);
      i.putExtra("TaskID", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TaskID")));
      i.putExtra("EmpID", empid);
      startActivity(i);   
   } 
       });

Comment: android:onClick="myClickHandler"

Comment: public void myClickHandler(View v) 
  {
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
   String url = "http://medev01.aa.com";
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
   Uri u = Uri.parse(url);    
   i.setData(u);    
   try {   
   startActivity(i);   
   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {   
     Toast.makeText(context, "Browser not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
   }
  }

Comment: Now add all that code to your question using the edit option.

Comment: I guess .... that's not a good idea. I changed my approch. anyways.... thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView with delete button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750380/android-listview-with-delete-button)

Answer (score 9):

Read this excellent blog post: [Focus problems with list rows and ImageButtons](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html)

Essentially you should add the following to your root layout element in the row-item xml.

> `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Answer (score 0):

that is the concept. If u want to implement both clicks then write button click normally and for list item click did not use the listitem click.

Instead that you write onclick listener for converted view that you returned in getview()

Then both clicks will work